# Get categories found in query

Tags: wordpress, tags, categories

I need to build a list of all categories and tags that contain a search result for a wordpress query.

e.g. a search in WP for "lorem" delivers 5 posts. Each of the posts has another category. How can I get all the category names? I know how to get the number of posts ($wp_query->found_posts) but not the found category names.

thx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

found it... duh!

`<?php get_the_category_list(); ?>`

thx